# How to split a sentence into two parts

Tags: java

How to split a sentence into two parts in JAVA? If there is the following

```
String sentence = "I love Java <=> I love Python"
```

How can I return `I love Java` and `I love Python` thus separately ignoring `<=>`?

```
public void changeSentence(String line)
{
    String[] words = line.split(" ");

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        if(!(words[i].equals("<=>")))
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using the method given below of class String

```
METHOD: (public String[] split(String regex, int limit)
```

- Regex: The String/Character you wish to remove & split remaining text
- Limit: How many String that should be returned

```
public class TestSplit

{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String str = new String("I Love Java <=> I Love Python");
        
    
        for (String retval: str.split("<=> ",2))
        {
            
                System.out.println(retval);
        }


    }
}
```

Output:

> I Love Java
>
> I Love Python

---

There are some other facts I am aware about are listed below

- If you won't specify limit by 'keeping it blank'/'specify 0' then the compiler will split string every time '<=>' is found
  e.g.

```
public class TestSplit

{

    public static void main(String args[])

    {

        String str = new String("I Love Java <=> I Love Python <=> I Love Stackoverflow");
        for (String retval: str.split("<=> "))
        {
                System.out.println(retval);
        }


    }
}
```

Output:

> I Love Java
>
> I Love Python
>
> I Love Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
String[] words = line.split("<=>");
for(String word : words){
        System.out.println(word); 
}
```

Output:

> I love Java
>
> I love Python

Answer (score 0):

public String[] changeSentence(String line){
String[] substrings = line.split("<=>");
return substrings;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can also split with StringTokenizer.

The code for splitting the strings based upon delimiter is below:

```
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sentence,"<=>");
        while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            System.out.println(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
        }
```

I hope this helps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*How can I return I love Java and I love Python thus separately ignoring <=>?*

First of all as you have said that you want your method to return separate words 
(Strings technically), for that you need change your return type from **void** to **String[ ]**

Second, you are using
`String[] words = line.split(" ");`
this will split the *String* where spaces appear which would yield you array of Strings containing

```
I
love
Java
<=>
I 
love
Python
```

as different words stored as separate `Strings` in your `words` array.

so what you should do is
    `Strings[] words=line.split("<=>");`
and return *words*

Full code should be like this

```
public String[] changeSentence(String line)
{
    String[] words = line.split("<=>");
    return words;
}
```